# How to search android app based on mime type in market

Tags: java, android, google-play

Most of the applications in the Market comes up with the intent filters. How can I search the apps in the Google play based on the MIME type

i.e
Example: How can i search like `market://search?q=type:text/pdf` or something else..

I haven't found something like this that suits to my requirement in the android developers site  also I have searched a lot in google I haven't found any. Thanks in Advance

Comment: The mime type of what exactly? Could you please be more specific and tell what is this going to be used for?

Comment: @g00dy I it is clear... Every application supply intent filter for the type of data it supports example   <data android:mimeType="text/plain" /> in the intent filter.. is it possible to search based on the data it supports...

Comment: Or simple example how can I search specific application i.e For imageViewer mime type image/* for  pdf, application/pdf etc

Comment: @Androiduser that is different..

Comment: Well that's taken from the manifest, if you click on the "Install" button you can only see part of it, but I don't think that there are the MIME types.

Comment: @g00dy Google Play will look at the Manifest when you are upload apk...example it identify the app version from the Manifest....

Comment: @Pragnani - yes it does, but it doesn't show al lthe information in t he Play Store - do you agree? I opened the Adobe Acrobat reader there and it was nowhere to be found, that the MIME type is `pdf` (and it sure is).

Comment: @g00dy check this..http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive.html, Manifest also have supported data information...It won't show in google play

Comment: @Pragnani - exactly my point! Then the answer is clear - there's no way to know the MIME type of an application, solely based on the url from GP.

Comment: @g00dy I think you have completely misunderstood the question...When google play can read the manifest can't it have the information of application supported data..? I want to search apps based on that information

Comment: @user1780366 - well correct me if I'm wrong, but the only place to see the Manifest information is when you click on the button `Install`. For example, I have Acrobat Reader installed and looking at its manifest on my phone I see: `android:mimeType ="application/pdf"`, but this is not showing on the web. I don't know other source of information regarding the Google Play apps and I don't think there is.